# Xcode 4 share IPA "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, ipa

I want to test my app on real device not emulator and I try to create archive from my app and share it to IPA but when i save IPA i get this error "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory".

What's going wrong?

Is the reason that i i don't have Identity Profile to set?

[image]

IS THERE ANY CHANCE TO SHARE IPA if i don't have apple developer certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For distributing apps to users (not to apple store) you must have Apple Developer Program. You can purchase it from here if you don't have yet. http://developer.apple.com/

After getting activation of developer program.

1. Create Distribution Certificate
2. Create AppID
3. Add Devices on which you want to install app
4. Create Ad hoc distribution or debug provision profile.
5. Build and run App with the created provision profile in Release mode.

Answer (score 3):

> IS THERE ANY CHANCE TO SHARE IPA if i
>   don't have apple developer
>   certificate?

The definitive response is : no.