# Create IPA file in Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.0 Beta version

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am developing app using Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.0 beta version. I want to create ipa.
For that I have selected product-->archive option After the Archive operation completes, then go to the Organizer, selected archive, then selected Share and in the "Select the content and options for sharing:" pane set Contents to "iOS App Store Package (.ipa) and Identity to iPhone Distribution (which should match ad hoc/app store provisioning profile for the project). 
After making all these settings, clicked Next then it disaplays save dialog. Giving ipa  name clicked save. Then it shows error as"Operation couldn't be completed. No such file or directory" and ipa creation process stops.

Is there going anything wrong?
How can I create an .ipa file with Xcode 4.2 iOS 5.0 beta?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465328/xcode-4-share-ipa-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Both Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 are under nondisclosure agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [**How to create an IPA (Xcode 4)**](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4). Although this is described for iOS 4, my guess is it would work for iOS 5

Comment: the first step i cant find.  there is no section labelled "code signing" or "entitlements"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your adhoc-profile selected in your scheme?